# Pause Popup Div to ask HTML5 Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a popup div that open on button click, it has one mandatory input field and submit button.When clicked on submit button popup hides and it does not show any required field message, what I want to do is to ask for required field when button is clicked.

Div code

```
<div id="city-popup" style="display:none;">
<div class="container">
    <form id="cityForm" name="cityForm" onsubmit="return false;">

        <div class="city-box">
        <img class="closed-city" src="/tripkar/resources/booking/images/popup-close.png">
        <div class="city-top">Add City</div>

        <div class="cityErrMsg"></div>
        <div class="city-input-feild"><p>City</p><input id="newCityName" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" class="city-txt-bx border-right" type="text"></div>



        <div class="city-button">
        <button class="add-city-btn" type="submit" onclick="javascript: return addCity();" >Add</button>
        <button class="city-cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript Function

```
//OK -- working fine
function addCity() {

    if ($("#cityForm")[0].checkValidity()) {

        console.log('addCity');
        return true;

    } else {
        console.log("invalid city form");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<form id="cityForm" name="cityForm" onsubmit="addCity();">
      <div class="city-box">
        <img class="closed-city" src="/tripkar/resources/booking/images/popup-close.png" />
        <div class="city-top">Add City</div>
        <div class="cityErrMsg"></div>
        <div class="city-input-feild">
          <p>City</p>
          <input id="newCityName" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" class="city-txt-bx border-right" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="city-button">
          <button class="add-city-btn" type="submit">Add</button>
          <button class="city-cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

and maybe modify ur function to hide the pop-up after the validation has been successfully done.

```
function addCity() {

if ($("#cityForm")[0].checkValidity()) {

  $(this.event.target).closest("#city-popup").hide();
    return true;

} else {
    console.log("invalid city form");
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: It is not working as i want, I want that when i submit form with empty field it shows required message and remains open.

Comment: @diyasher: can u check out this plunkr once, and lemme know the issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/hDClZkNLfU5UsiPaa1vX?p=preview